# Make platformer character stay in the air at the top of a jump

Tags: unity, 2d, physics, platformer, jumping

I have a player who can jump. I want the character to stay in its position and not fall to the floor.

This is the code I am using so far:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
        if(moveup)
        {
            rigid.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 1f, 0) * speed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            moveup = false;
        }
}
```

How can I stop the character from falling?

Answer (score -1):

Just change the

```
void Update()
```

to

```
void UpdateFixed()
```

I hope this solves your problem.

But turn off the collider for the player and make sure you have a rigidbody on ALL assets.

Also, make sure the character isn't in the ground when the game starts.

Comment: It's FixedUpdate, not UpdateFixed. They already use FixedUpdate. Also you provide a lot of things they should check, but no reason for doing so; better teach them how to fish than just provide them with the fish.